# Ill-Conditioned Model Error

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, inequality

**Problem**:

> Consider a linear regression problem where we observe noisy observations,
> $$y=Xw^* + \epsilon,$$
> where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ represents the data matrix ($n$ points and $d$ features), $w^*\in\mathbb{R}^n$ represents the ground truth, and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$ represents some noise. Suppose $X$ is ill-conditioned (i.e. $\kappa(X)\gg 1$) and we take $\hat{w}=X^{-1}y$ as an estimate for $w^*$. What can I say about this quantity?
> $$ \lVert \hat{w}-w^*\rVert_2$$

**Thoughts**: Well, following our nose we see

$$ \lVert \hat{w}  - w^*\rVert_{2} = \lVert X^{-1}y - w^* \rVert_{2} = \lVert X^{-1}(Xw^* + \varepsilon) - w^*\rVert_{2}=\lVert X^{-1}\varepsilon \rVert_{2}.$$

With Cauchy-Schwarz, I can see (letting $\lambda_{\min}$ denote the smallest characteristic value of $X$)

$$ \lVert \hat{w}  - w^*\rVert_{2}\leq \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}}\lVert \varepsilon\rVert_2.$$

**Question**: I guess I'm lamenting the lameness of this upper bound. If $\lambda_{\min}\geq 1$, then this actually isn't a bad estimate for $w^*$ right? Just because the condition number is high doesn't mean $\lambda_{\min}$ has to be tiny - it's just that it's tiny in comparison to $\lambda_{\max}$. I guess the idea here is that this error *could* be large provided $\varepsilon$ is large in norm and/or $\lambda_{\min}$ is tiny? Is there a lower bound for this that's more interesting?